# Prove $n^2+1$ is even if and only if $n$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I got the side of $n$ is odd, prove $n^2+1$ is even by: $n=2k+1$, $n^2+1=4k^2+4k+2$,
$n^2+1=2m$ (so it is even).

But I don't know to prove from $n$ is odd, then $n^2+1$ is even.

Comment: Did you try  proving the contrapositive (if n is not odd, n^2+1 is not even)?

Comment: "But I don't know to prove from $n$ is odd, then $n^2+1$ is even":  you proved that in your first line. You need to prove that "if $n$ is even, then $n^2+1$ is odd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then we can write $$n=2k+1$$ and we get$$(2k+1)^2+1=4k^2+4k+1+1=4k^2+4k+2=2(2k^2+2k+1)$$ and this is even.

Answer (score 1):

$n^2-1+2=$

$(n-1)(n+1)+2$ is even

$\iff$ $(n-1)(n+1)$ is even

$\iff$ n is odd.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It suffices to show $n^2$ is odd iff $n$ is odd.

**Hint 2:** Consider the contrapositive.

Answer (score 0):

If $n^2+1$ is even you want to show that $n$ is odd.

You may approach by contradiction.

Assume that $n$ is not odd, then $n$ is even that is $n=2k$

$$n^2+1= (2k)^2+1 = 4k^2+1$$ which is odd, contrary to our assumption that $n^2+1$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$(n^2+1) $ has the same parity than $(n^2+1+2n) $ which is $ (n+1)^2$.

thus $n^2+1$ is even if only if
$(n+1)^2$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

there is a direct proof:

$"\Rightarrow":$

$n^2+1:even\Rightarrow n^2+1-1:odd\Rightarrow n^2 odd\Rightarrow n:odd$

$"\Leftarrow":$

$n:odd\Rightarrow n^2:odd\Rightarrow n^2+1:even$

I think that's enough